# Not able to load data from an external file into the ipython module

Tags: python, ipython

I am not able to load the data from an external file into the ipython console. I used loadtxt function and even after specifying the exact text file named primes.txt in my desktop i write that location of the file it is not being recognized.EX:i write the  command loadtxt("primes.txt") in the ipython console it then comes primes.txt not recognized. Please help.

```
primes=loadtxt("primes.txt")
OSError: primes.txt not found.
```

This comes even though the file is present in the desktop and clearly mentioned.

Comment: `"clearly mentioned"` Nothing in `loadtxt("primes.txt")` "clearly mentions" that the file is on the desktop and not in the working dir

Comment: If your working dir is not a desktop then it **clearly** won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Mention proper directory to load the file.
Note: It is recommended that you keep the data file at the same location where you created the jupyter notebook